# Dll code to C source code

Tags: c, dll

I have a Dll file . This is written by using C . How can i convert this into C source file.
   I call this Dll file from java . While i calling one of the function it gives me NaN return
   value. I found that cause of this problem might be in C function . So i need to get that
   function definition .

Comment: do u want to get the C file from a dll???

Comment: Yes, my need is to get C file from dll .

Answer (score 3):

You can not easily "convert" a DLL into source.  If the DLL is part of an open source project, or you can obtain original source for it from a vendor, an internal development team, etc., then you might proceed that way.   Apart from trying to reverse engineer it with a disassembler (ugly, and not what you're asking for), there's no simple method to do what you are asking.